# Combine 2 circuits to get the best of both? Battery management system

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, 555

I'm working on a battery management system for 2 12V batteries in series, totalling 24V, and I found this very good blog online with 2 circuits that got me very interested:

[This](http://homemadecircuitsandschematics.blogspot.pt/2013/03/automatic-lead-acid-battery-charger.html) one, that got me for it's simplicity and apparent ease of use by just including a relay.

And [this](http://homemadecircuitsandschematics.blogspot.pt/2013/08/3v-45v-6v-9v-12v-24v-automatic-battery.html) one that got me for its use of an LED driver to indicate battery status.

The thing here is, I would like to maintain the simplicity of the first but include the LED driver, my doubt arises because I don't know if I can just get the LED driver part from the second and put it on the first, where to put it, and how to put it there. If you guys could give me a hand on this, it would be really great.

Also, I want your opinion on something. I can't get enough current from the batteries I'm using to supply the load (a 24V DC motor), it needs around 2A and the batteries are only supplying around 1A, making the motor terribly slow and way less effective. It doesn't need to run for more than say 15 seconds, ever, so what I though of was a Super capacitor bank that gets me 27,5V max charge and 1,6F capacitance, and with this, I know I could supply enough current for to motor to run, or at least start off (the 2A stabilize on around 1,3A after it's initial peak). The thing is, I don't know how to calculate for how long it can supply this current, since capacitor's voltage will drop when it is supplying the needed current, making the power vs time graph not linear, instead, a curve.

You might ask, why not just change the batteries? Well, I could do that, but I would need a bulkier battery, which doesn't interest me for this project. Also, I can easily get the batteries I'm using, while all other options, I would have to find a supplier...

What do you guys think of this? Is it stupid to try to use super capacitors is these conditions? Do you think it will not be cost effective? I got a nice deal off of ebay and they are already on it's way here, If not for this project, for something else, because I've been wanting to "play around" with super capacitors for a while now :p

EDIT: The batteries are 2 small sealed lead acid 12V 1.3Ah, i want to keep the system small, that's why i thought of supercaps.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: can you describe exactly what battery you ARE using?

Comment: Also i dont think you understand fully the issues of using supercaps, They have extremely low voltage ratings, and they need special attention when charging them. You can get special super-cap charger ICs, for example Texas Instruments have some that do it.

Comment: I think this would be much better split into two separate questions: 1) how to combine circuits 2) use of supercaps for startup current. e.g. use the EDIT button to cut the second part and later paste it into a new question. Refer to the original question if needed.

Comment: Alright, i am aware of the low voltage on supercaps, that's why i speak of a bank, and not a cap. i will use 5 series 5.5V supercaps and have 2 banks in paralell to compensate for capacity loss. also, do you really think the charger ic is necessary?

Comment: Im sorry, im editing the question to include battery type

Comment: Even a small SLA battery should be able to supply the current you need for the motor, so that problem must be elsewhere, perhaps in your driver circuit.

Answer (score 2):

### Q1. Combining circuits (charger + indicator)

You can add a [LM3915  Dot/Bar Display Driver](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm3915.pdf)
 as a competely separate circuit connected to the battery (in parallele with the charging circuit).

I'd use the example circuit in the datasheet. You can derive the VLED supply in the same way as in the second circuit or use a resistor dropper as the data sheet suggests.

### Q2. Supercaps to boost start-up current

> I can't get enough current from the batteries I'm using to supply the load (a 24V DC motor), it needs around **2A** and the batteries are only supplying around 1A ...  It doesn't need to run for more than say **15 seconds**, ever.

I don't see why supercaps should be necessary. Normal 12V lead-acid batteries of the sort used in automotive applications should have no trouble supplying 2A for a short period. Many automotive batteries can supply hundreds of amps for 30 seconds at 0°F.

Automotive Lead-Acid batteries have a current rating sometimes referred to as CCA (cold cranking Amps). This is in Amps (and is mostly unrelated to the rated capacity in Amp-hours).  So long as you don't exceed this there should not be a problem.

For example the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1696431.pdf) for a Yuasa 1.2Ah 12V battery gives

```
Maximum discharge (A) 12 
Short Circuit current (A) 36
```

The discharge chart suggests it can supply a **2.4A** current (2C = 2 x 1.2 = 2.4A) for **6 minutes** (down to 11V).

[image]